# What are $d_1$ and $d_2$ for Laplace?

Tags: black-scholes, probability, stochastic-processes, distribution

What are the formulae for `d1` & `d2` using a [Laplace distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is interesting because I thought that the only chance with Lévy-processes is to use Fourier-transform approaches (see e.g. Cont,Tankov).

But in the paper [Option Pricing for Log-Symmetric
Distributions of Returns by Fima C. Klebaner· Zinoviy Landsman](http://www.cmss.monash.edu.au/assets/files/KlebanerLandsman2007.pdf) they consider models, where the log of the price has a symmetric distribution. In Corollary 3.2 they propose an approximate formula if the log of the price follows the Laplace distribution where
$$
d_{1,2} = \frac{\ln(S_0/K) + (r \pm log(1-\sigma^2/2))T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}.
$$
They write $\log$ but I guess this is just an $\ln$ as before. But please try yourself and/or read the first pages of the paper to be sure.

Comment: Good to hear that. I have to play a bit with this distribution myself. Your other questions in this context look interesting too...